# RedirectToAction won't redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

I'm having a problem with redirecting from controller's method.
From .cshtml file i send some parameters to method in controller like this:

```
function callCancelMethod(data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Account/CancelAction",
                data: data,
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error("Error while making AJAX POST request: " + error);
                }
            });
        }

$("#cancelButton").on("click", function () {
            callCancelMethod({ cancelUrl: cancelUrl });
        });
```

In controller I have this method but it doesn't redirect to either hardcoded url that I pass it or to ("Index", "Dashboard", new { Area = "ECon" }); that already works in another methods:

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CancelAction(
            string cancelUrl
            )
        {
            var isDevEnv = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsDevEnvironment"];

            if (isDevEnv != null && isDevEnv.ToLower() == "true")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
            }

            return Redirect(cancelUrl);
        }
```

In console or network tab I don't see any errors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call an AJAX method, it won't perform any redirect. Redirects are performed when you POST a form, or follow a link (GET)

You can change the location client side

```
 function callCancelMethod(data) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Account/CancelAction",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
               window.location = "/Dashboard";
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.error("Error while making AJAX POST request: " + error);
            }
        });
    }
```